# could not initialize proxy - no Session (Grails Runtime Exception)

Tags: session, grails

I am using Grails 1.2.2 and I got this message sometimes.

It usually happen if I got logged in the apps and the I tried to type url of home apps (http://localhost:9090/apps/)

the error screen grab :

[alt text http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/9982/ss20100609025018.png](http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/9982/ss20100609025018.png)

for bigger view : http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/9982/ss20100609025018.png

and the main.gsp code was in  http://pastebin.com/Z9QKj5kw

Can someone tell me how to fix this error ?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem and was able to fix it by calling refresh() on a domain object I had attached to my session, as detailed here:

[Grails 1.0.4 "no Session" Error](http://tech.favoritemedium.com/2008/12/grails-104-no-session-error.html)